# How to stop html textarea from interpreting html entities into their characters

Tags: html, jsp, xhtml, textarea

I have an html textarea that is used to display a string from a database. The textarea can be edited and any changes are saved to the database.

The problem is that when it recieves entities &reg; in a string it converts them into their characters, and then when the text is saved the characters overwrite the entities. For example: The database would return the string Microsoft&reg; which would be displayed as Microsoft®, and then saved that way. Is there a way to force textareas to not interpret entities?

Follow up: my thought right now is to, on getting the string from the database replace all '&' with '&amp;'. But I'm still wondering if there is a way to stop textareas from converting the strings they recieve.

Comment: do you know what kind of unicode your database is using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to escape HTML entities? You can use either JSTL [`<c:out>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) or [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<textarea><c:out value="${bean.text}" /></textarea>
```

or

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<textarea>${fn:escapeXml(bean.text)}</textarea>
```

It will by default escape under each `&` to `&amp;` so that for example `&reg;` ends up to become `&amp;reg;` and this way it will be *displayed* as `&reg;`.