# Displaying xml in textarea without rendering htmlentities

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, html-entities

I've been reading about this for a while now and can't find the solution.
This looks like the solution I need:
[How to stop html textarea from interpreting html entities into their characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636956/how-to-stop-html-textarea-from-interpreting-html-entities-into-their-characters)

But when I do this I just get  in the textarea. What gives?

This is my first time trying to use jstl. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's `text()` method and assign it to text area.

Comment: I can't do that because it begins with <?xml and that throws an unterminated string literal