# Passing HTML string to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a value that I'm currently accessing and passing to a JavaScript function through an `onclick`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openTextWindow('<%=myVar.varDefinition.getText()%>');">Text</a>
```

An example value that I'd receive from the `getText` method is shown below.

```
<h1>My Header</h1><br />My text
```

This value is then passed to my `openTextWindow` method.

```
function openTextWindow(inText) {
    myWindow = window.open('','','width=500, height=300');
    myWindow.document.write(inText);
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

For some reason, the value stored in `inText` doesn't match the string with HTML tags that I showed above. It ends up looking like this.

```
"<lt/>h1<gt/>My Header<lt/>/h1<gt/><lt/>br /<gt/>My text
```

When `inText` is written to `myWindow`, I want that new window to render with the text `My Header` within a styled header and `My text` on a line below that. I've tried replacing and escaping characters with no luck. Any ideas on how to fix this or a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: <%=myVar.varDefinition.getText()%> This is neither js nor html.

Comment: Sorry, I figured this was a problem that would need to be solved in JS so I didn't include JSP in my tags.

Comment: Your jsp is obviously the source of the problem.

Comment: As in I need to clean the string before I call it via JSP?

Comment: I have no idea what <%=myVar.varDefinition.getText()%> is supposed to be replaced by, because i don't know jsp, and because people who do probably need more context informations.

Comment: It's not supposed to be replaced by anything. That's how I get the HTML string I had in my original post.

Comment: When simply writing the getText(), you'll end up with invalid HTML like so: `<a href="#" onclick="openTextWindow('<h1>My Header</h1><br />My text');">` You need to replace the HTML characters like `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. JSP can do that as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636956/how-to-stop-html-textarea-from-interpreting-html-entities-into-their-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stash your HTML in a hidden DIV or textarea, then grab that from your function instead of trying to pass it inline.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openTextWindow('DIV1');">Text</a>
<div id="DIV1" style="display:none"><%=myVar.varDefinition.getText()%></div>
```

JS:

```
function openTextWindow(divName) {
    var inText = document.getElemenyById(divName).innerHTML;
    myWindow = window.open('','','width=500, height=300');
    myWindow.document.write(inText);
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: I started adding some of this in but I have to run to lunch. I'll let you know how it works out! Thanks.