# Print xml source in html page

Tags: html, xml, printing

So I have a servlet which prints content of various files. But when I want to print .xml file my servlet page doesn't print anything, because page uses this xml tags as html and is parsing them istead of printing. And I want to print this tags. I am reading file line by line and lines are stored in variable line.

Comment: You must return the correct content type header. Which platform you use for your application?

Comment: Windows, NetBeans, but it have to work on linux (it's jboss servlet). Reading file and writing it out is in java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print xml content in your HTMl page, you can use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) function from Apache commons lang library to write xml file contents to your HTML page

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("<html><head></head><body>");
writer.write(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(xmlContent);
writer.write("</body></html>");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to **Display XML as content in an HTML document**:

Browsers can't tell the difference better a `<` that the author intends to mean "Start of tag" and one that the author intends to mean "Render this".

You need to represent it as `&lt;` if you want it to appear as data.

The answer to [htmlentities equivalent in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328381/htmlentities-equivalent-in-jsp) explains how to convert a string of text into a string of HTML.

---

If you are attempting to **Output an XML document instead of an HTML document**:

You need to specify an XML content type (such as `application/xml`) instead of an HTML content-type.

See [How to set the content type on the servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216190/how-to-set-the-content-type-on-the-servlet) for an explanation.

Comment: First case, it's working, thanks. But if someone know a method without writing new function I'd be thankful. Greets.